# C++ Array based on external file

Tags: c++, arrays, function, file, upload

I have relatively simple problem (at least it seems like that to me). Let's say I have a file 'test.txt' containing 9 lines of numbers like this:

```
8 4
1.2 2.3
3.4 4.5
2.8 2.1
3.1 9.4
1.2 2.3
3.4 4.5
2.8 2.1
3.1 9.4
```

The first number (8) tells me how many rows of floats will follow the first line, another one (4) is a number needed for further computation. Then we have a table 8x2 containing points coordinates. Now I try to write a simple function, which (once called) would create my data based on content of external file.

Here is my code:

```
// Function to display matrix
void showMatrix(float *matrix, int size)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        printf("%5f ",*matrix);
        matrix++;
    }
    matrix -= size;
    printf("\n");
}

// Function to upload single file
void loadInputFile(std::string file_name, float* data_X, float* data_Y, int& data_size, int& centre_interval) {

    // Open text file
    std::ifstream dataFile;     
    dataFile.open(file_name.c_str());
    if (!dataFile.good())
     return;

    // First line contains data size and another number:
    dataFile >> data_size >> centre_interval;
    printf("Loading data...\nLoaded values: dataSize = %d, centreInterval = %d\n", data_size, centre_interval);

    // Create data tables under specified pointers:
    data_X = new float[data_size];
    data_Y = new float[data_size];
    printf("Created table of size %d\n", data_size);

    for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i++) {
        dataFile >> data_X[i] >> data_Y[i];
    }

    // No error - loaded correctly
    showMatrix(data_X, data_size);

    // Close file
    dataFile.close();
}


int main(int argn, char ** argc) {

    // I want it to be filled by my function
    float* dataX;
    float* dataY;
    int dataSize;
    int centreInterval;

    // My file name existing in the same path
    std::string filename = "test.txt";

    // Calling my function
    loadInputFile(input_names[i], dataX, dataY, dataSize, centreInterval);

    // Loaded correctly
    printf("Data load results:\n dataSize = %d,    centreInterval = %d\n", dataSize, centreInterval);

    // Error :/
    showMatrix(dataX, dataSize);

    return 0;
}
```

I am able to correctly store this data inside my function, but there seems to be an error in my way of passing it outside. Would appreciate pointing out my mistake.

Comment: On two unrelated notes, I suggest you stop using `printf` in C++, and also to start using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg printf seems to be the easiest way to look at the content of my data in most cases (including computations on cluster). Is there any alternative then?

Comment: `std::cout`? You can format just like `printf` using [manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip), and it's *type safe*, you don't have to think about if it should be `"%d"`, `"%hu"` or `"%lld"` or anything like that.

Comment: Oh, right... With these manipulators, it seems to be far more flexible. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `dataX` and `dataY` arguments *by value*, which means they are *copied* and inside the function you only allocate memory for the local copies and not the original.

Change the function to

```
void loadInputFile(std::string file_name, float*& data_X, float*& data_Y, int& data_size, int& centre_interval)
```

Comment: Yes, this works. It's funny to notice how I used exactly the same method for simple values and didn't realize I can do that for arrays... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @irchris102: The same happens for simple values (POD). Pass the simple values in, modify them inside the function and the original values (outside the function) will remain unchanged (unless you pass them by reference).